# SwiftUI hide the arrow in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swiftui

Very simple question, I searched the whole world about how to hide the damn arrow in NavigationLink but none of the even close. [image]

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewKnock()) {
                    Image("knock_hand_icon").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).padding(3)
                    }.fixedSize()
```

I believe it's just add some modifiers or so. Thanks

Comment: Did you see my answer? Didn't it work?

Answer (score 3):

Be creative. You can use `ZStack` with an `EmptyView` to achieve that. Something like:

```
ZStack {
    Image("knock_hand_icon").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).padding(3)
    NavigationLink(destination: NewKnock()) {
        EmptyView()
    }.fixedSize()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now there does not appear to be an official way to address this. I would assume a lot of these customizations will come in future versions of SwiftUI. That being said my work around is to place the content on a very high zIndex and adjust padding to move the content over the arrow.

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewKnock()) {
  Image("knock_hand_icon")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
    .padding(3)
    .zIndex(999999)
    .padding(.trailing, -16)
}
```

You'll have to play with it a bit, but the `.trailing` padding of -16 moves the image over the arrow coupled with the `zIndex` that will ensure it is above the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I solved using overlay, although I tried other solutions but the didn't worked.

Here is solution for your code

```
Image("knock_hand_icon").resizable().frame(width: 40,height: 40).padding(3)
.ovelay(
NavigationLink(destination: NewKnock()) {

                }.fixedSize().opacity(0.0))
```

you can replace image with your custom view or cell as well